# How do I decode a website if it isn't utf-8 in python?

Tags: python, utf-8

The following is my setup for a web scraping program:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re

url = http://roosters5.gepro-osi.nl/roosters/rooster.php?&school=x with x being the number of the school
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Normally, this returns the html file in which I can search for what I want with `re.findall()`, however, this doesn't work with some school numbers such as 218.

What causes this and how should I fix this?

Comment: examine the http response headers and/or http headers to see what charset it WAS served up in.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, it may be a good idea to look at ``lxml2``, which for example can parse meta-tags as well and help you to decode entities like ``&auml;``

Comment: @MarcB Charset=windows-1252 for all of the sites, however decoding it using windows-1252 doesn't work. Could you explain what you mean in detail?

Comment: With which number does it work? Does it work with in browser with both numbers? What exactly do you mean by _"does not work"_?

Comment: @zvone with it does not work I mean that I cannot decode it. This varies day by day, currently `[218, 337]` don't work, but `[25, 33, 36, 41, 47, 59, 63, 65, 80, 81, 89, 97, 139, 178, 179, 181, 185, 191, 199, 211, 213, 222, 228, 231, 232, 285, 288, 302, 319, 348, 356, 358, 368, 385, 387, 397, 398, 400, 401, 406, 415, 418, 419]` do work

Comment: _"Cannot decode"_ raises an exception for utf-8? Probably, but I am sure it does not raise an exception for windows-1252 (it shouldn't even if the content is not windows-1252). So what happens then?

Comment: @Iterniam what happens when you decode it with 1252? Is there an error?